# An issue about image style changed by 3DLUT (look up table)

Tags: image, video, linear-algebra, lookup-tables

This is Charlie. I am a new guy in image processing.
I have a question. It seems complicate to me, hopfully someone can do me a favor...

Here is my issue.

step 1. I use 3DLUT Creator create a coffee style LUT, that is a **.cube** file with `64x64x64` entry.

step 2. I write a simple C program. This program is to open a landscape BMP file (32bit per pixel), get the pixel by pixel, then use the coffee LUT to change image style. Then a new image with coffee style is generated. The simple trilinear interpolation is used in this C program.

**Problem:**
While I find that my new image seems a little wierd. Some colors seems not correct, compared with the image generated by 3DLUT Creator. Some part of green trees seems too dark, not consistent with other parts.
I double check the C code. The trilinear interpolation seems not difficulty. Even I ask chatgpt to generate the code, but I get the same result, the generated image is still not correct.

Here is the my sample code:

```
// get the pixle with RGB value from a bmp file

float Red = R * (LUT_TABLE_SIZE - 1) / 255.0f;  // R is original pixel Red value
redL = (int) Red ;
redH = redL + 1
if( redH == LUT_TABLE_SIZE )  // prevent overlow
   redH = redL ;
..... 
..... // get Green greenH,greenL, Blue,blueH, blueL, the same way as Red,redH, redL. 
.....
indexH=redH+N∗greenH+N∗N∗blueH   // index of LUT table
indexL=redL+N∗greenL+N∗N∗blueL

colorH=table[indexH]   
colorL=table[indexL]

dec_R = Red − redL;
....  // get the dec_G, dec_B the same way

NewR=(colorH.red−colorL.red)∗dec_R+colorL.red
NewG=(colorH.green−colorL.green)∗dec_G+colorL.green
NewB=(colorH.blue−colorL.blue)∗dec_B+colorL.blue

/// write the new pxile to new bmp
```

Can anyone with more image processing experience do me a favor?

1. Are there anything wrong in my code?
2. If code is correct, then after we change the image with 3DLUT, shall we do some other things to make image become more normal? (*ie:* no color inconsistent etc).

Here are the images.
The Coffee LUT table is generated by 3DLUT Creator.
To make sure that the LUT table is correct, I try Davinci Resolve, it is perfect.

[image after LUT wit my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7LAd.jpg)

[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mrRw.jpg)

[image after the same LUT with Davinci Resolve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aapvU.png)

[image after the same LUT with 3DLUT Creator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn0eR.jpg)

Comment: First, your RGB channels looked mixed up. Did you know **BMP uses B-G-R order** (a reverse arrangement of the usually expected R-G-B order)?

Comment: yes, you are right.  I check the RGB of LUT and BMP.   RGB channels  doesn't match.  I change the  "indexH=redH+N∗greenH+N∗N∗blueH  " to  "indexH=blueH+N∗greenH+N∗N∗redH  "  , then the new image becomes normal.  Thank you.